# how to explain the anova object for a multivariate linear regression?

Tags: r, multivariate-regression

I performed a multivariate linear regression such that:

```
fit<-lm(as.matrix(y)~mwtkg+mbmi+mage,data=x)
```

where $y$ is a $500 \times 26$ multivariate outcomes. Then, I am wondering how to explain the `anova(fit)`:

```
> anova(fit)
Analysis of Variance Table

             Df  Pillai approx F num Df den Df    Pr(>F)    
(Intercept)   1 0.99959    63064     25    651 < 2.2e-16 ***
mwtkg         1 0.03506        1     25    651    0.5403    
mbmi          1 0.20862        7     25    651 < 2.2e-16 ***
mage          1 0.09016        3     25    651 4.567e-05 ***
Residuals   675                                             
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

What do the three Dfs, Pillai, and P values mean for the model?

Comment: Are you using `anova` from the stats package?

Comment: yes. Not the `car::Anova`.

Comment: R is pretty terrible with anova, given that it defaults to sequential sums of squares. Why are you fitting your model with `lm`?

Comment: what's the best way to fit a multivariate regression model where both the multiple responses and predictors are continuous variables?

Comment: I guess I usually use `glm`, but I don't deal with much continuous multivariate data.

Comment: Anyway, Pillai's trace is a multivariate statistic (like Wilk's lambda or Lawley-Hotelling trace). The first df is the number of degrees of freedom of the model term (which clearly are all continuous) and the next two dfs are the numerator and denominator degrees of freedom for calculating the F statistic. The p-value is the test that the probability of the observed data is greater than F.